# Tomcat won't allow me to send @POST requests using Jersey (Jax-RS)

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, http, tomcat

I have been trying (for about a day now) to figure out how to send a @POST request from my client to my web service but I am getting a 403 error and I have no idea why.  I have tried editing my web.xml files to allow the correct authorization but it still isn't working.  Below are my WEB-INF web.xml and Tomcat web.xml files.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, this has been beyond frustrating. Also, I am very new to both Tomcat and Jersey so it very well could be a very stupid/simple error.

Specs

- OS X El Capitan 10.11.2
- Tomcat Version 7.0 Server
- Eclipse JEE Kepler R Cocoa x86_64
- Jersey 2.23.1
- JRE 1.7
- Postman as my client (Google chrome ext)

Server web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>readonly</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,Connection,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Referer,Token-Id,User-Agent, X-Requested-With</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD</param-value>
    </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

WEB-INF web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.messenger</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: 403 is forbidden.. .........

Comment: yes, I don't want it to be though and I don't know how to fix it.  FWIW, it was a 405 error until i added the CorsFilter.

Answer (score 0):

That should not happen. Your error is handled somewhere. Look these annotations:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
@ExceptionHandler(YourException.class)
```

Comment: where do i find that?

Answer (score 0):

This example (https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/java-journal/jersey/) has a somewhat altered web.xml:

```
<display-name>Jersey Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

That example page seems to highlight your exact environment (except the author uses IntelliJ rather than Eclipse... but you can download the community edition for free, and Java 8 rather than 7) - so you may want to follow along with it to get up and running.